# Behavioral differences with std::move(*this) from a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Given the class definition:

```
struct MoveOnly
{
    MoveOnly(int v_)
    : v(v_)
    {
        std::cout << ((void*)this) << " MoveOnly " << v << "\n";
    }

    ~MoveOnly()
    {
        std::cout << ((void*)this) << " ~MoveOnly " << v << "\n";
    }

    MoveOnly(const MoveOnly&) = delete;
    MoveOnly& operator=(const MoveOnly&) = delete;

    MoveOnly(MoveOnly &&src)
    {
        v = std::exchange(src.v, -1);
        std::cout << ((void*)this) << " MoveOnly&& " << v << "\n";
    }

    MoveOnly& operator=(MoveOnly&&) = default;

    MoveOnly&& Apply()
    {
        std::cout << ((void*)this) << " Apply " << v << "\n";
        return std::move(*this);
    }

    int v;
};
```

The console shows for code:

```
auto m1 = MoveOnly(1);
m1.Apply();

> 0x7fff5fbff798 MoveOnly 1
> 0x7fff5fbff798 Apply 1
> 0x7fff5fbff798 ~MoveOnly 1
```

Now, if I change `Apply` to return a value instead of an r-value reference:

```
MoveOnly Apply()
{
    std::cout << ((void*)this) << " Apply " << v << "\n";
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

I see:

```
auto m1 = MoveOnly(1);
m1.Apply();

> 0x7fff5fbff798 MoveOnly 1
> 0x7fff5fbff798 Apply 1
> 0x7fff5fbff790 MoveOnly&& 1
> 0x7fff5fbff790 ~MoveOnly 1
> 0x7fff5fbff798 ~MoveOnly -1
```

The first example seems to preserve the original object, which goes against my intuition for what std::move does.  Although since it doesn't invoke the move constructor, I can see how the original object would still have a `1`.

What I'm trying to figure out here is how the C++ standard explains this behavior and what the uses cases for the different version of `Apply()` might be.

Comment: What is your intuition for what `std::move` does? Maybe it's wrong. `std::move` doesn't *do* anything, it's just a cast.

Comment: In the first case `m1`'s type should be `MoveOnly &&`. The value is never moved anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm slowly coming to terms with the fact that `std::move` doesn't actually do anything.  This article helped me clarify things a lot: http://jlebar.com/2016/5/28/A_Practical_Introduction_to_C%2B%2B11_Rvalue_References.html

Answer (score 3):

`std::move` does not "do" anything. All that it does is cast an lvalue into an rvalue. Example:

```
class Foo { ... };

void leave(Foo && f) {}

void take(Foo && f) { auto g = std::move(f); }

Foo f;

leave(f); // this won't compile, bar wants an rvalue

leave(std::move(f)); //  this compiles, but f is not changed in any way

take(std::move(f)); // compiles, and leaves f in the moved from state
```

The original version of `Apply` doesn't do anything on its own, but it can enable other things. For example, assuming the original definition of `Apply`:

```
auto m1 = MoveOnly(1);
m1.Apply(); // does nothing
auto m2 = m1; // doesn't compile
auto m2 = m1.Apply() // Does compile, and does something! moves m1 to m2
```